# gradleでサブフォルダ内のファイルをフォルダから全て出してコピーする方法

Tags: android, android-studio, cocos2d-x, gradle

cocos2d-xでアプリをAndroidでビルドすると、
Resourcesフォルダ内のファイルが全てAndroidのassetsフォルダ内にコピーされます。

build.gradle

```
task copyAssets(type: Copy) {
    from '../../Resources'
    into 'assets'
}
```

この部分を変更して、Resourcesフォルダ内にあるサブフォルダの中身のファイルを全て
サブフォルダから出した形でassetsフォルダにコピーしたいです。
図で描くと下のようなことです。

このようなResoucesフォルダの中身を、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
このようにassetsフォルダにコピーしたいです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このようにファイルをコピーするためにはbuild.gradleにどのように記述すればいいでしょうか。

なお、実際にはResources内のサブフォルダはたくさんあるので、
サブフォルダ名やファイル名を具体的に指定することなく、
このようなコピーを行いたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
task copyAssets(type: Copy) {
    from fileTree('../../Resources').files
    into 'assets'
}
```

でどうでしょうか。

参考:

- [How do I flatten when copy? - Old Forum - Gradle Forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-flatten-when-copy/5491/4)
- [Working With Files - Gradle User Guide Version 3.0: 18.3. File trees](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:file_trees)
- [FileTree (Gradle API 3.0)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileTree.html#getFiles())

Comment: ありがとうございます。しかし、android studioでRebuild Projectすると期待どおりのコピーが出来るのですが、cocos compile -p android --android-studioでビルドすると、build.gradleが実行される前に、別の処理でResourcesフォルダがコピーされているらしく、Resourcesフォルダがそのままassetsにコピーされた後、build.gradleに書いたコピー処理が行われます。android-build.pyの中のcopy_resourcesをコメントアウトしても同様でした。どこを直せばいいかわかりますでしょうか？

Comment: proj.android-studio/build-cfg.jsonを編集してResourcesフォルダが全てコピーされるのを防ぐことができました。